# Adding disk to VmWare ESXI 5.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

We had some issues with our disk and had to replace it. We reloaded VmWare ESXI on new disk and currently trying to attach the old disk again to server.

We are not sure if we should proceed further with adding datastore. We are stuck at a point in adding datastore:

[image: Where we are stuck]

We have data on the old drive and while adding datastore there is a warning that data will be permanently lost.

Please suggest how should we proceed.

Answer (score 3):

ESXi should automatically pick up any existing datastores if you do a rescan on the controllers - the `rescan all...` button:

[image: Rescanning controllers]

A more detailed instruction can be found in the [vmware knowledgebase](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003988)